# Display data in android listpopupwindow on edittext click using mysql php

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

After doing lots of brain storming i endedup doing it hard coding ,Actually what my program does is on clicking on the edit text a listpopupwindows shows with hard coded array list such as friends name.Now what i want is i want to retrieve the my friends name from mysql database table and show the same in listpopupwindow.Actually i m getting the data from rest client api(php) using volley as network library and String request but the problem is cannot able to display it on listpopupwindow once i clicked on edittext..Dont know how to do it,tried a lots searching.Any sample code?

Comment: what do you mean with `listpopupwindow`?

Comment: display names from mysql in android listpopupwindow

Answer (score 0):

Yes, First you need a JSON/REST API ( may be any kind of API your choice ). There after using any Http client to get the list and populate to the list this tutorial is help to you much [enter link description here](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: did the json rest api..get data in json format but i dont know how to display the json data in listpopupwindow(dropdownlist)..

Comment: now you are populating from the lish nah!, so push the data to the list from the response object/array